# Profile Picture not updating

Tags: picture, image-upload

I just want to know why my Profile Picture not updating in sharepoint after I uploaded and saved my new picture. I need to close the page or refresh several times for me to see the changes.

Replication steps

1. Accessed the site
2. Edit My Profile
3. Changed my Profile picture
4. Save and Close
5. My profile picture is still the same as before

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to go through these steps,

1. Create an import PictureURL mapping
2. Perform a full profile synchronization
3. Run the Update-SPProfilePhotoStore PowerShell command
4. Create an import PictureURL mapping
5. Perform a full profile synchronization

Or

You can go through this [awesome](http://sharepointadam.com/2010/11/18/import-user-profile-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2010/) tutorial with pictures.